# Problem with this mySQL query: (using WHERE with AS clause)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My SQL query is working fine, until I try to add a 'WHERE distance < 10' and 'chunk-of-calculation AS distance' on 4th and 10th line respectively. Any idea how I can fix it? Thanks!

```
Unknown column 'distance' in 'where clause'

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS places.*, category.*, 
COUNT(places_reviews.place_id) AS num_reviews, 
(places_popularity.rating_1 + 2*places_popularity.rating_2 + 3*places_popularity.rating_3 + 4*places_popularity.rating_4 + 5*places_popularity.rating_5)/(places_popularity.rating_1 + places_popularity.rating_2 + places_popularity.rating_3 + places_popularity.rating_4 + places_popularity.rating_5) AS average_rating, 
6371 * acos( cos( radians(places.lat) ) * cos( radians( 1.29315 ) ) * cos( radians( 103.827164 ) - radians(places.lng) ) + sin( radians(places.lat) ) * sin( radians( 1.29315 ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM (places) 
JOIN category 
ON places.category_id = category.category_id 
LEFT JOIN places_reviews ON places_reviews.place_id = places.id 
LEFT JOIN places_popularity ON places_popularity.place_id = places.id 
WHERE `places`.`category_id` = 1 AND `distance` < 5 AND places.name LIKE '%%' GROUP 
BY places.id 
ORDER BY id desc 
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to put the formula in your WHERE clause instead of using the alias distance.  In a SQL query, the WHERE clause is evaluated before the SELECT statement so the alias (in this case `distance`) does not exist yet.  Here is what your SQL statement will look like:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS places.*, category.*, 
COUNT(places_reviews.place_id) AS num_reviews, 
(places_popularity.rating_1 + 2*places_popularity.rating_2 + 3*places_popularity.rating_3 + 4*places_popularity.rating_4 + 5*places_popularity.rating_5)/(places_popularity.rating_1 + places_popularity.rating_2 + places_popularity.rating_3 + places_popularity.rating_4 + places_popularity.rating_5) AS average_rating, 
6371 * acos( cos( radians(places.lat) ) * cos( radians( 1.29315 ) ) * cos( radians( 103.827164 ) - radians(places.lng) ) + sin( radians(places.lat) ) * sin( radians( 1.29315 ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM (places) 
JOIN category 
ON places.category_id = category.category_id 
LEFT JOIN places_reviews ON places_reviews.place_id = places.id 
LEFT JOIN places_popularity ON places_popularity.place_id = places.id 
WHERE `places`.`category_id` = 1 
   AND (6371 * acos( cos( radians(places.lat) ) * cos( radians( 1.29315 ) ) * cos( radians( 103.827164 ) - radians(places.lng) ) + sin( radians(places.lat) ) * sin( radians( 1.29315 ) ) )) < 5
   AND places.name LIKE '%%' GROUP 
BY places.id 
ORDER BY id desc 
LIMIT 5
```

The only way you could refer to `distance` by name would be to wrap your statement and make it into a table in a new SELECT statement.  For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM ( <insert your original query here without the WHERE distance= statement ) AS t
WHERE distance < 5
```

Comment: the formula is really long, is there any way to shorten it like using the AS clause?

Comment: @Nyxynyx - I just updated my post to reflect how to do this.  Note though that you will need to evaluate the query execution plan to figure out the performance benefits/drawbacks to each.

Comment: do u know if including the formula in the WHERE clause will cause the formula to calculate anything? Just wondering

Comment: @Nyxynyx - I believe it will calculate twice (once in the WHERE, once in the SELECT).  It all depends on how your data is set up though whether it would be better to wrap the statement in another SELECT statement.  It may be that it is more efficient to do so rather than do the calculation twice or it may be that the ability to filter out records first is more efficient.  It will take some experimentation to determine that.

Comment: @Nyxynyx It looks like `distance` Only references columns in the `places` table? If so maybe create a view with it in and substitute the view into your query instead.

Comment: i'm not familiar with views, so my question will be whether using views will work with the result of the long formula having variables passed to it from php

Comment: @Nyxynyx - I would say just use my code for now.  It will make life easier.  Yes you can interact with a view like you can a SELECT statement but it will mean creating the view on the server.  Also, if you are creating any of these numbers (above in your statement) from php, it will be harder to do so in a view since the SELECT statement is on the server, not in your code where you can manipulate it.